# Http failure response for http url: 401 Unauthorized

Tags: java, angular, authentication, spring-security, http-status-code-401

When ever I use the following method I am able to call my service from angular

```
   @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
        http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/").permitAll();
    }
```

but when I change the configure method as below I am getting 401 error.

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity.csrf().disable()
                // dont authenticate this particular request
                .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/authenticate", "/register","/basicauth").permitAll().
                // all other requests need to be authenticated
                        anyRequest().authenticated().and().
                // make sure we use stateless session; session won't be used to
                // store user's state.
                        exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint).and().sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);

        // Add a filter to validate the tokens with every request
        httpSecurity.addFilterBefore(jwtRequestFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }
```

How to overcome this problem.

my error as below

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the entire endpoint in `antMatchers()`. As far as I can see, the url you're trying to reach is `.../api/v1/basicauth` => change the **/basicauth** string to **/api/v1/basicauth**.

Comment: Another solution could be to use **/*/basicauth** and it's more general (the mapping before *basicauth* can be anything). But for authentication purposes it's better in my opinion to use the full endpoint.